# Error when use reset method of FormGroup using angular2-tinymce library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have used FormGroup to build my form. I need a nice textarea component then I choose angular2-tinymce library/package to build form.
Here's my html template:

```
  <form (submit)="submitCallLog($event)" [formGroup]="callLogForm">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" formControlName="title">
    <div [hidden]="callLogForm.controls.title.valid">
      <p><i>Title is required</i></p>
    </div>
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <app-tinymce id="content" formControlName="content"></app-tinymce>
    <button type="submit" class="right-align">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

My Class:

```
export class NewCallLogComponent implements OnInit {
  isNewCallLog = false;
  callLogForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private callLogService: CallLogService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.callLogForm.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
      console.log('Changed: ', values);
    })
  }


  createForm () {
    this.callLogForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      content: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }


  resetFormValue() {
    this.callLogForm.reset();
  }

  submitCallLog(e) {
    console.log('Event: ', e);
    e.preventDefault();
    this.isNewCallLog = false;
    const cusId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    const newCallLog = new CallLog(
      new Date().toLocaleString(),
      this.callLogForm.value.title,
      this.callLogForm.value.content,
      'anonymous'
    );
    this.callLogForm.reset();
    this.callLogService.addCallLog(cusId, newCallLog);

  }
}
```

After submit form, everything ok except catching error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at o.setContent (http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:13388:23574)
    at TinymceComponent.webpackJsonp.452.TinymceComponent.writeValue (http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:659:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:21277:29
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22463:65
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at FormControl.setValue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22463:28)
    at FormControl.reset (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22518:14)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22822:21
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22861:66
    at Array.forEach (native)
View_NewCallLogComponent_0 @ NewCallLogComponent.html:5
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14091
DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:12981
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1144
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:9373
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.es5.js:2683
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:414
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4117
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:413
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:181
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
NewCallLogComponent.html:5 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 12, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
View_NewCallLogComponent_0 @ NewCallLogComponent.html:5
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14091
DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:12981
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1149
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:9373
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.es5.js:2683
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:414
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4117
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:413
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:181
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
```

The error cause the form can't be reset. Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a late reply but maybe someone else also got this.
I encountered a similar issue while using custom component wrapper for tinyMCE. The problem in my case was that when you trigger form reset the ControlValueAccessor writeValue method is called with null as parameter.
I've corrected they issue by using a simple condition to avoid setting the tinyMCE editor content to null.

Hope this helps!